# Jmeter Script-Error Message in Response Data but Successful result in sample Result

Tags: jmeter

While running Jmeter scripts, one of the step is failing but Successful Result is coming in Sample Result as:

```
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 200
Response message: OK
```

But error message is coming in Response Data as:

```
Unfortunately, we could not delete your entire itinerary because of a database synchronization error.  
If you could please re-load your itinerary and try again, we would appreciate it.
Thank you for your patience.
```

I need to re-submit the Request for that i am using the While loop comparing the Response Data then try to resubmit the request which is not working as.

```
if(ResponseData.equals("Unfortunately")==true)
{
    log.error("Database synchronization error...Re sending Request");
    vars.put("resubmitflag","true");
}
```

The problem i believe that i am not using correct functions for it as 
ResponseData.equals will not work as how we can compare whole response data 
which is not possible.

Kindly anyone help how to proceed and what functions need to use for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about B[eanshell Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor), there are a couple of issues with your code.

1. `ResponseData` isn't something, which is available to Beanshell Post Processor. You need either use `data` (which is byte array previous sampler response representation) or `prev` (which stands for SampleResult class for previous sampler).
2. `equals` method checks 2 strings for being identical. In your case you need to consider either `startsWith` or even `contains` method.

See following code samples for reference

```
String response = new String(data);
if (response.contains("Unfortunately")){
    log.error("Database synchronization error...Re sending Request");
    vars.put("resubmitflag","true");
}
```

or

```
String response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
.....
```

See [How to use BeanShell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details.

Hope this helps